# How to prevent duplicate when insert data in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert (if it's not exist) from .csv file to my tables. I have tried INSERT IGNORE and REPLACE. However these doesn't work in this case, so I still got duplicate. So what should I do to prevent duplicate when I insert? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (name VARCHAR(255), Mac_address VARCHAR(255));
LOAD DATA INFILE '/automateupdate/mac_list.csv'
INTO TABLE temp_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (name, Mac_address);

INSERT INTO attributevalue(object_id, object_tid, attr_id, string_value)
SELECT o.id, o.objtype_id, 9999, t.Mac_address
FROM temp_table as t, object as o, attributevalue as attr
WHERE attr.attr_id = 9999 and o.name = t.name and attr.object_id = o.id;
```

Comment: It should work if you've defined a `UNIQUE KEY` on the columns that define whether it's a duplicate or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on all the columns in `attributevalue`, you could use `INSERT IGNORE` to prevent duplicates.

If you can't do that, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` with the table so you only return rows from `temp_table` that don't match what's in `attributevalue`.

```
INSERT INTO attributevalue(object_id, object_tid, attr_id, string_value)
SELECT o.id, o.objtype_id, 9999, t.Mac_address
FROM temp_table AS t
JOIN object AS o ON o.name = t.name
JOIN attributevalue AS attr ON attr.object_id = o.id
LEFT JOIN attributevalue AS attr1 
    ON attr1.object_id = o.id 
        AND attr1.object_tid = o.objtype_id 
        AND attr1.attr_id = 9999 
        AND attr1.string_value = t.Mac_address
WHERE attr.attr_id = 9999
AND attr1.object_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I just tried your query, and I still got duplicates. 

Here is the result that I've ran from your query........
Query OK, 389 rows affected (0.86 sec)
Records: 389  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: You need to see the sample data of import file or the current data that needs to be updated?

Comment: I need both, so I can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I couldn't put the sample data into sqlfiddle, So I uploaded to this, http://textuploader.com/atvil . Thanks.

Comment: But the names in your CSV file don't match any of the names in `object`. And there are no rows in `attributevalue` with `attr_id = 9999`. So when I ran my query it didn't insert anything.

Comment: Sorry, this data is really large, so I just cut it off into a small piece of data and pasted into the sample data, here is the attr_id = 9999 data look like, (74, 4, 9999, '00:15:60:0F:43:67', NULL, NULL), (75, 4, 9999, '00:1D:49:79:30:B0', NULL, NULL), (77, 4, 9999, '00:1E:79:69:2E:8A', NULL, NULL)

Comment: You still need to add entries to the "object" table whose names match the names in the CSV file. Please update the fiddle so it has enough data to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an index, the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE maybe work:

`INSERT INTO attributevalue (object_id, object_tid, attr_id, string_value) VALUES (valueObjectId, ....) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE string_value = 'value', ...`

Check the MySQL docs for this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html